# Unable to write to JSON file in dart using flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am able to read a JSON file but I can’t seem to write to or update a JSON file. I’m able to update a JSON string but can’t seem up write my json string to a file. The code below is the what I used to read the file. However, I’m not able to then write to the same file.

```
new ListTile(

        title: new Text("Close" ),
        trailing: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
        onTap: loadpos,
      )
class NewPage {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  NewPage({this.title,this.color});
}


Future <String> _loadpos() async{
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/button.json');
  }

Future <String> loadpos() async{
  String jsonword = await _loadpos();
//  _parseJsonForPos(jsonword);
  List data = json.decode(jsonword);
 // data[0]["backgrndcolor"] = "black";
  print(data[0]["navbar"]);
}


String _parseJsonForPos(String jsonString) {
  List data = json.decode(jsonString);

  print(data[0]["_value"]);

}
```

Assets file: (button.json)

[{"navbar" : "top"}]

Printed Value:

```
Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 5 of 430 libraries in 1,474ms.
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/flutter (15546): top
I/art     (15546): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 222431(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 93% free, 911KB/12MB, paused 553us total 113.423ms
I/art     (15546): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 222396(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 92% free, 1027KB/13MB, paused 523us total 124.949ms
Lost connection to device.
```

- The problem that I am currently facing is that I am unable to write and update the value to JSON file.

In pursuit of trying another way to read and write to a JSON file, I used another method to create and write to the JSON file but I’ve found that this only temporarily stores and reads and does not write to a JSON file.

From what I understand on Android, the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() method returns the AppData directory. However, when I searched within this directory on my phone, I could not find my button.json file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

  TextEditingController keyInputController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController valueInputController = new TextEditingController();

  File jsonFile;
  Directory dir;
  String fileName = "button.json";
  bool fileExists = false;
  Map<String, dynamic> fileContent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
      dir = directory;
      jsonFile = new File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
      fileExists = jsonFile.existsSync();
      if (fileExists) this.setState(() => fileContent = JSON.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyInputController.dispose();
    valueInputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void createFile(Map<String, dynamic> content, Directory dir, String fileName) {
    print("Creating file!");
    File file = new File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
    file.createSync();
    fileExists = true;
    file.writeAsStringSync(JSON.encode(content));
  }

  void writeToFile(String key, dynamic value) {
    print("Writing to file!");
    Map<String, dynamic> content = {key: value};
    if (fileExists) {
      print("File exists");
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonFileContent = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(JSON.encode(jsonFileContent));
    } else {
      print("File does not exist!");
      createFile(content, dir, fileName);
    }
    this.setState(() => fileContent = JSON.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync()));
    print(fileContent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("JSON Tutorial"),),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("File content: ", style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          new Text(fileContent.toString()),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0)),
          new Text("Add to JSON file: "),
          new TextField(
            controller: keyInputController,
          ),
          new TextField(
            controller: valueInputController,
          ),
          new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Add key, value pair"),
            onPressed: () => writeToFile(keyInputController.text, valueInputController.text),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TL;DR: I’m able to create a json string but unable to write it to a json file

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish but you may need to write to the app's storage. That probably doesn't map to a file on the device. I saw this suggestion https://flutter.io/flutter-for-react-native/#local-storage. There may be other libraries for writing large amounts of data to the app's storage. If you need to read/write real files to the file system, https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html should work. Were you getting specific errors when trying to use that? I'm not sure how directories and app permissions work with that.

Comment: Sorry if my description wasn't clear enough.

Essentially, what I want to do is read a JSON file, then if needed update a value in that JSON file.

So far, I've been able to read the JSON file, encode a JSON string but can't write the JSON string to the JSON file.

Thank You

Comment: Where did the JSON file come from? I'm not sure you can edit files in your assets directory. Someone can correct me but usually if you are saving user preferences or something you'd use the iOS/Android native storage APIs. If you are reading/writing something like word documents, PDFs, images, or some large file to/from the user's SD card then you could get permission to access the filesystem and do so.

Comment: Ah. I think you're right. That makes alot of sense. I think that's also why the youtube tutorial i watched used the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() method. According to the flutter documentation that uses the ANdroid or iOS API to store the file in the appropriate directory as you mentioned. I guess my approach of using Assests to keep a user preferences file is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Use `shared_preferences` to keep a user preferences file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the json file created is inaccessible is because `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` was used. Path for this is '/data/user/0/{PACKAGE_NAME}/app_flutter' and I don't think it's accessible using the device's file browser.

I suggest using `getExternalStorageDirectory()` as it writes files on '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{PACKAGE_NAME}/files' and is easily accessible.

Here's some screenshots from running the repro you've provided.

[image]

Json file is accessible using a file browser

[image]

Opening the json file displays the same Strings written in the file

[image]